# Move object by clicking on another object

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i need some help.

When i click on a arrow i want a red,blue and yellow square to move out of the screen.
and when i click the arrow again i want the squares to come back out again.

Here is the code. The code may look really bad beacuse i am new to css and html. :3

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="TEST.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Index.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="social">
<a href="#"><img id="REDSquare" src="Images/youtube-icon.png" width="50px" height="60px" /></a>
<a href=""><img id="BLUESquare" src="Images/Facebook-icon.png" width="50px" height="60px" /></a>
<a href="#"><img id="YELLOWSquare" src="Images/PMC logo 3D.png" width="50px" height="60px" /></a>
<img id="Arrow" src="Images/arrow.png" width="50px" height="60px" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
body{
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background:#999;
    min-height:500px;
    }
    #social #REDSquare{
                    position:fixed;
                    margin-top:19.8%;
                    margin-left:-1px;
                    display:inline-block;
                    background:#e11b2b;
                    border:solid 1px #e11b2b;
                    border-left:solid 1px #e11b2b;
                    width:60px;
                    height:60px;
    -moz-transition: ease-in 0.2s;
    -o-transition: ease-in 0.2s;
    transition:ease-in 0.2s;
                    }
                    #social #BLUESquare{
                    position:fixed;
                    margin-top:23%;
                    margin-left:-1px;
                    display:inline-block;
                    background:#3b579d;
                    border:solid 1px #3b579d;
                    width:60px;
                    height:60px;
    -moz-transition: ease-in 0.2s;
    -o-transition: ease-in 0.2s;
    transition:ease-in 0.2s;
                    }
                #social #YELLOWSquare{
                    position:fixed;
                    margin-top:26.3%;
                    margin-left:-1px;
                    display:inline-block;
                    background:#CC0;
                    border:solid 1px #CC0;
                    border-left:solid 1px #CC0;
                    width:60px;
                    height:60px;
    -moz-transition: ease-in 0.2s;
    -o-transition: ease-in 0.2s;
    transition:ease-in 0.2s;
                    }
                                    #social #Arrow{
                    position:fixed;
                    margin-top:30.1%;
                    margin-left:5px;
                    background-color:transparent;
                    border: 2px solid transparent;
                    border-radius:25px;
                    display:inline-block;
                    width:40px;
                    height:40px;
    -moz-transition: ease-in 0.3s;
    -o-transition: ease-in 0.3s;
    transition:ease-in 0.3s;
                    }
#social #BLUESquare:hover{
        border-left: solid 20px #3b579d;
        }
#social #YELLOWSquare:hover{
        border-left: solid 20px #CC0;
        }
#social #Arrow:hover{
            background-color:#000;
            border:2px solid #000;
                    }
#social #REDSquare:hover{
        border-left: solid 20px #e11b2b;
        }
```

Srry if there is not a picture. I am not reputaion 10 yet :(

If you can send a link to a website that explains how to do it or if you could write a comment, it would be greatly appreciated

P.S Srry for bad english. Im from Sweden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution written in pure JS:

```
var arrow = document.getElementById("Arrow");
var redSquare = document.getElementById("REDSquare");
var blueSquare = document.getElementById("BLUESquare");
var yellowSquare = document.getElementById("YELLOWSquare");
var iconsHided = false;

toggleIcons = function (){

    if (iconsHided == false) {

        iconsHided = true;
        redSquare.style.marginLeft = "-62px"
        blueSquare.style.marginLeft = "-62px"
        yellowSquare.style.marginLeft = "-62px"


    } else {

        iconsHided = false;
        redSquare.style.marginLeft = "-1px"
        blueSquare.style.marginLeft = "-1px"
        yellowSquare.style.marginLeft = "-1px"

    }

}


arrow.addEventListener("click",toggleIcons)
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/e0pdftm5/1/

I see that you are trying to position your icons by using %. This may be not working in the way you expect as you can see in the example fiddle. And I think you are over-complicating your structure. Try maybe to animate whole div with content and use class to define similar styling for your icons. Here is the example:

```
<div id="social">
<a href="#"><img class="socialIcon" id="REDSquare" src="Images/youtube-icon.png" width="50px" height="60px" /></a>
<a href=""><img class="socialIcon" id="BLUESquare" src="Images/Facebook-icon.png" width="50px" height="60px" /></a>
<a href="#"><img class="socialIcon" id="YELLOWSquare" src="Images/PMC logo 3D.png" width="50px" height="60px" /></a>

</div>

<img id="Arrow" src="Images/arrow.png" width="50px" height="60px" />
```

CSS:

```
body {

  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background:#999;
  min-height:500px;
}

#social {

  position:fixed;
  top:20%;
  left:0px;
  width:60px;
  -moz-transition: ease-in 0.2s;
  -o-transition: ease-in 0.2s;
  transition:ease-in 0.2s;

}

.socialIcon {

  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  -moz-transition: ease-in 0.2s;
  -o-transition: ease-in 0.2s;
  transition:ease-in 0.2s;
}

#REDSquare {

  background:#e11b2b;
  border:solid 1px #e11b2b;
  border-left:solid 1px #e11b2b;

}

#BLUESquare {

  background:#3b579d;
  border:solid 1px #3b579d;
  border-left:solid 1px #3b579d;

}

#YELLOWSquare {

  background:#CC0;
  border:solid 1px #CC0;
  border-left:solid 1px #CC0;

}

#Arrow {

  position:fixed;
  top:350px;
  left:5px;
  background-color:transparent;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius:25px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  -moz-transition: ease-in 0.3s;
  -o-transition: ease-in 0.3s;
  transition:ease-in 0.3s;
}

#BLUESquare:hover{
  border-left: solid 20px #3b579d;
}
#YELLOWSquare:hover{
  border-left: solid 20px #CC0;
}
#Arrow:hover{
  background-color:#000;
  border:2px solid #000;
}
#REDSquare:hover{
  border-left: solid 20px #e11b2b;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var arrow = document.getElementById("Arrow");
var socialIcons = document.getElementById("social")
var iconsHided = false;

toggleIcons = function (){

    if (iconsHided == false) {

        iconsHided = true;
        socialIcons.style.left = "-62px"

    } else {

        iconsHided = false;
        socialIcons.style.left = "-1px"

    }

}

arrow.addEventListener("click",toggleIcons)
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/e0pdftm5/2/

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question. When the squares are hidden is there any way i can make so that the arrow changes directrion and is pointing outwards?

Comment: You welcome! You can change an image of the arrow by changing src attribute after click. Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/e0pdftm5/4/ or you can also rotate it using by CSS transforms.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin like this is probably what you're looking for.

http://visionmedia.github.io/move.js/